# constrain a series or array to a range of values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a series of values that I want to have constrained to be within +1 and -1.

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10000))
```

I know I can use `apply`, but is there a simple vectorized approach?

```
s_ = s.apply(lambda x: min(max(x, -1), 1))
s_.head()

0   -0.256117
1    0.879797
2    1.000000
3   -0.711397
4   -0.400339
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
s = s.clip(-1,1)
```

Example Input:

```
s = pd.Series([-1.2, -0.5, 1, 1.1])

0   -1.2
1   -0.5
2    1.0
3    1.1
```

Example Output:

```
0   -1.0
1   -0.5
2    1.0
3    1.0
```

Comment: This does something *slightly* different, but is nonetheless good to know!

Comment: @AndyHayden: Huh? It gives the same output as what I get running the example code in the question and piRSquared's answer.  Or am I missing subtle?

Comment: mine discards values out of the between range, yours caps them at the min/max. As seen from the 0th item in your example.

Comment: Ha! clip is what the OP wanted!

Comment: I didn't know this `clip` method, ty +1

Comment: I was conflicted... ultimately I decided that I learned more from this answer.  And it's prettier.

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `np.where`

```
pd.Series(np.where(s < -1, -1, np.where(s > 1, 1, s)))
```

---

#### Timing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) Series method:

```
In [11]: s[s.between(-1, 1)]
Out[11]:
0   -0.256117
1    0.879797
3   -0.711397
4   -0.400339
5    0.667196
...
```

Note: This *discards* the values outside of the between range.

Comment: Ooops, this *discards* the values outside the between range. Going to leave this here anyway (as it could be what someone finding this answer may want).

Comment: I was also unaware of `between` +1.

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion:

```
s[s<-1] = -1
s[s>1] = 1
```