# filling cells in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I created the DataFrame and faced a problem:

```
      r       value    
0    0.8     2.5058
1    0.9    -1.9320
2    1.0    -2.6097
3    1.2    -1.6840
4    1.4    -0.8906
5    0.8     2.6955
6    0.9    -1.9552
7    1.0    -2.6641
8    1.2    -1.7169
9    1.4    -0.9056
...   ...    ...
```

For r from `0.8` to `1.4`, I want to assign the value for `r = 1.0`.
Therefore the desired Dataframe should look like:

```
   r       value    
0    0.8    -2.6097
1    0.9    -2.6097
2    1.0    -2.6097
3    1.2    -2.6097
4    1.4    -2.6097
5    0.8    -2.6641
6    0.9    -2.6641
7    1.0    -2.6641
8    1.2    -2.6641
9    1.4    -2.6641
...  ...    ....
```

My first idea wast to create the condition:

```
np.where(data['r']==1.0, data['value'], 1.0)
```

but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Are there always the same number of elements in every group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def subr(df):
    isone = df.r == 1.0
    if isone.any():
        atone = df.value[isone].iloc[0]
        # Improvement suggested by @root
        df.loc[df.r.between(0.8, 1.4), 'value'] = atone
        # df.loc[(df.r >= .8) & (df.r <= 1.4), 'value'] = atone
    return df

df.groupby((df.r < df.r.shift()).cumsum()).apply(subr)
```

[image]

Comment: I had a similar solution, but yours is a little more clever. Note that you can use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) instead of multiple conditions: `df.r.between(0.8, 1.4)`.

Comment: @root I should have remembered that from http://stackoverflow.com/a/38668861/2336654.  I've added it to the answer, thx

Answer (score 1):

Starting with this:

```
   r   value
0  0.8 -2.6097
1  0.9 -2.6097
2  1.0 -2.6097
3  1.2 -2.6097
4  1.4 -2.6097
5  0.8 -2.6641
6  0.9 -2.6641
7  1.0 -2.6641
8  1.2 -2.6641
9  1.4 -2.6641


df3['grp']   = (df3['r'] ==.8).cumsum()
grpd         = dict(df3[['grp','value']][df3['r'] == 1].values)
df3["value"] = df3["grp"].map(grpd)
df3          = df3.drop('grp', axis=1)


     r   value
0  0.8 -2.6097
1  0.9 -2.6097
2  1.0 -2.6097
3  1.2 -2.6097
4  1.4 -2.6097
5  0.8 -2.6641
6  0.9 -2.6641
7  1.0 -2.6641
8  1.2 -2.6641
9  1.4 -2.6641
```

Comment: It's not the solution. I don't want to set 1.0, but values for r = 1.0

Comment: added another. solution